# How to prove this simple randomized algorithm is 2-approximate for MAS?

Tags: approximation

The Maximum Acyclic Subgraph (MAS) problem is:

> Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$, find
> the largest subset of edges which are acyclic.

In [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4389531) the authors state the following algorithm:

> A simple randomized algorithm achieves a factor 1/2 for
> this problem: Simply pick a random ordering of the vertices. In fact, one can achieve factor 1/2 by an even simpler
> algorithm: Pick an arbitrary ordering of the vertices $\pi$ and
> its reverse $\pi^R$. One of them has at least 1/2 fraction of the
> edges in the forward direction.

How can we prove that this is indeed a 2-approximation algorithm? I'm having trouble understanding what a reverse of an ordering could be, and what a "forward" direction is (since we're not dealing with network flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the approximation guarantee for any algorithm, we mostly aim to find a lower bound on the optimal value (for *minimization problem*) or an upper bound on the optimal value (for *maximization problem*).

Since yours is a maximization problem, a trivial upper bound is $|E|$ for the optimal value since any solution is a subset of $E$ and thus contains less than $|E|$ edges.

Now, let us see how we get $2$-approximation. Take any arbitrary ordering of vertices: $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$.

1. Let $|E_f|$ be the set of edges that goes forward, i.e., all edges in $E_f$ are of the form $(v_i, v_j)$ such that $i < j$. It is easy to see that this subset of edges forms an *acyclic subgraph*.
2. Similarly, $E_b$ be the set of edges that goes backward, i.e., all edges in $E_b$ are of the form $(v_i, v_j)$ such that $i > j$. This subset of edges forms an *acyclic subgraph* as well.

It is easy to see that either $|E_f| \geq |E|/2$ or $|E_b| \geq |E|/2$.

Since $\mathsf{OPT} \leq |E|$, we get $|E_f| \geq \mathsf{OPT}/2$ or $|E_b| \geq \mathsf{OPT}/2$.

In other words, either $E_f$ or $E_b$ is a $2$-approximation. The algorithm simply chooses the one with the maximum cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate why it is easy to see that $|E_f| \geq |E|/2$? I'm having trouble grasping that part.

Comment: @a6623 Okay. Tell me, what if both $|E_f|$ and $|E_b|$ are $< |E|/2$? what would happen to their sum?